# System cant access zip file due to other process in C#

Tags: c#

I'm not used to C# and this is the first real hurdle I came across. I'm used to php where these issues seem to be less prominent. In the code below, I create a new zipfile, textBox2.text meaning the destination location the user selected.

Then using the filestream, i open then the zip. After opening the zip, I created a for each loop in where I add the files into the zip using `CreateEntry`.

The error I'm getting is:

> System.IO.IOException: 'Kan geen toegang krijgen tot het bestand
>   C:\Users\windo\Desktop\Voedsel kelin\result.zip omdat het wordt gebruikt door een ander proces.'

Meaning it can't be accessed due to another process already accessing the file. The source code is below. It's behind a `button2_click`.

```
if (checkZip.Checked)
{
    string zipPath = textBox2.Text + @".\result.zip";

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(textBox2.Text, zipPath);
    string[] compressedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(textBox2.Text);

    using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open))
        foreach (string file in compressedFiles)
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry newRecord = archive.CreateEntry(file);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you by any chance have your zip file open in your operating system?

Comment: That's sure what it sounds like.

Comment: The destination map (Being textBox2.Text) is empty when the program runs.

Comment: If you get "is openened by another process", in 99% of all cases it is because you did not Dispose or Close the handles properly. In the other 1%, it is actually opened by another process!

Comment: @Christopher I would like to try that, whereabout would you place a closing function in the code?

Comment: The thing is, the issue is not the shown code. You are properly disposing of these handles, using the using block. | My guess was on `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()`. But that one has no return value. So any file it opens, it should close again. So there has to be some *other* code that creating that file. | The process as a whole makes little sense. You create a ZipFile - that is a gone and done deal. You then open the file as a FileStream and try to itterate over the string-lines of what is entirely binary data? And you do that to figure out the path???

Comment: Also if there is any kind of background process that tries to BackupFiles as soon as they are written, it has ample time to lock the file between `CreateFromDirectory()` closing the file and `new FileStream()` trying to open it. And it is a disk operation, so it will take some time.